# Odata V4 Client DataServiceContext Full Text Search

Tags: c#, linq, odata, wcf-data-services, iqueryable

I'm using Odata V4 DataServiceContext to fetch data from server.
I need to achieve following requirements.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string City{get;set;}
}
```

I need to do a full text search by querying any of the properties value is  matches to provided string value.
I can use below code to achieve this:

```
var searchString = "California";
IQueryable<Person> query = context.Person.Where(x=>x.Id.ToString().Contains(searchString) || x.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || x.LastName.Contains(searchString) || x.CityContains(searchString));
```

But I don't want to include all the properties in the expression like in above code. Also there will be an exception thrown if I compare string value with a non string property.

I need to make this more generic.

**Requirement 1**

```
IQueryable<Person> query = context.Person.Where(AnyOfPropertiesStringValue.Contains(searchString);
```

Here `AnyOfPropertiesStringValue` is a dummy method and I want to transform it to an executable code.

**Requirement 2**

```
IQueryable<Person> query = context.Person.Where(PropertiesStringValue("FirstName","LastName").Contains(searchString);
```

Here `PropertiesStringValue`is a dummy method and  I want to transform it to an executable code which will only compares the properties which name is passed as a parameter. In above example need to compare properties FirstName and LastName with provided string value.

Finally need to create an object of `IQueryable<Person>` type.

Could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: The data service must support full text search, which is a feature that was added in OData version 4.

Comment: Ok. How can I Implement that? Any code examples?